# How do you control CSS styles from within the CMS interface in Zotonic?

Tags: css, zotonic

I would like to give my creative colleagues access to the CSS through the Zotonic CMS user interface.

How do you control CSS styles from within the CMS interface in Zotonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One design idea was that css (and templates) need to be under version control.  That is why we kept the css (and templates) separate from the content-editing.

When your designers can use mercurial, then there is another way:

1. place your site under mercurial version control
2. clone your site on the server and install the site as usual
3. go to the zotonic status site (just use the ip address or a non-configured dns name)
4. log on (use the password in the zotonic `priv/config` file

Now you will see an "update" button behind your site.  When you click this button then a `hg pull -u` of your site is performed.  This will publish the new css (and other parts).

[image: Example of zotonic server screen]

Comment: That is a great solution.  Thank you Marc.  Having built-in version control integration is great.  I was trying to think of a decent way achieving that effect.